# SQL - updating a table using a reference table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables and i would need to update the table_1 using table_2 as my reference .

Table_1

```
ID  Type
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   2
A   2
A   1
B   2
B   2
B   1
B   2
B   1
B   1
B   2
```

Table_2

```
ID  Type_1  Type_2
A   Apple   Samsung
B   Samsung Apple
```

From the above i need to update the Type column in Table_1 using the Type_1 column in Table_2 where for ID = 'A' the Type 1 = Apple and 2 = Samsung

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the column [Type] of Table_1, this is the query:

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Type = CASE
            WHEN T1.Type = '1' THEN T2.Type_1
            WHEN T1.Type = '2' THEN T2.Type_2
            ELSE T1.Type
          END
FROM Table_1 T1
INNER JOIN Table_2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```

Is that the query you are asking for?

Hope this will help.